# how to stop audio playing in background in exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

```
**
```

### Need to implement video stream within a fragment using exoplayer. Streaming works fine but when moved from the fragment activity to other activity or if the screen is rotated, multiple copys of same audio plays in background continuously until the app is killed.how to handle this please help. Thanks in advance.

**

```
    public class VideoFragment extends Fragment {
    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    public SimpleExoPlayer player;
    Uri mp4VideoUri;
    String TAG ="LOGG";
    SharedPrefs sharedPrefs;
    TextView notavailable;
    String url;
    Connection connection;
    long media_length;

    public VideoFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_fragment,container,false);
        sharedPrefs = new SharedPrefs(getContext());
        connection = new Connection(getContext());
        notavailable= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videonotavailable);
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext(), trackSelector, loadControl);
        simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(getContext());
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeterA = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getContext(), Util.getUserAgent(getContext(), "exoplayer2example"), bandwidthMeterA);
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        url=sharedPrefs.getvideoUrl();
        if (url==null || url.equals("")){
            simpleExoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            notavailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else if (connection.isInternet()){
            mp4VideoUri=Uri.parse(sharedPrefs.getvideoUrl());
            MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mp4VideoUri,dataSourceFactory,extractorsFactory,null,null);
            final LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(videoSource);

            player.prepare(loopingSource);

            player.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
                    Log.v(TAG,"Listener-onLoadingChanged...");
                }

                @Override
                public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                    Log.v(TAG,"Listener-onPlayerStateChanged...");
                }

                @Override
                public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {
                    Log.v(TAG,"Listener-onTimelineChanged...");

                }

                @Override
                public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                    Log.v(TAG,"Listener-onPlayerError...");
                    player.stop();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {
                    Log.v("LOG","Listener-onPositionDiscontinuity...");

                }

                @Override
                public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

                }
            });
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }else {
            simpleExoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            notavailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            notavailable.setText(getString(R.string.nointernet));
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(player != null) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            media_length = player.getCurrentPosition();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(player != null) {
            player.seekTo(media_length);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You create a simpleExoPlayerView in a fragment. A usual way is creating a service in an activity/fragment. It will start only once, no matter how much the activity is recreated. I don't know how an ExoPlayer works, but if it doesn't start a service, you should correctly start and stop it in onCreateView/onDestroyView (or onResume/onPause) of a fragment or activity's onStart/onStop/onDestroy.

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment-holding activity, you need to handle the situation in the `onPause` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mPlayerFragment.pause();
}
```

You can define a method in your fragment to pause playback by passing false to `setPlayWhenReady()`.

```
public void pausePlayback() {
        mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false); //pauses the playback if it's playing
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue and problem resolved after implement below code in my existing code

First You need to create global variable

```
 boolean isActivityRunning = false;
```

Set this value in `onCreate()` and onResume() of activity to **true**.

You need to set Player if value `isActivityRunning` is **true**

After that you need to release player and set `isActivityRunning = false` in `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` that look like

```
 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isActivityRunning = false;
        releasePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isActivityRunning = false;
        releasePlayer();
    }

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        releasePlayer();
    }

  @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        releasePlayer();
    }
```

and `releasePlayer()` implementation look like is

```
 SimpleExoPlayer player;
 PlayerView playerUI;

     private void releasePlayer(){
            if(player!=null){
                player.release();
                player.clearVideoSurface();
                playerUI.getPlayer().release();;
    
    
                player = null;
                playerUI =null;
            }
        }
```

Where player and player UI is Global variable that need to set **null**

This solution work well for me.